# digital current monitor/sensor for monitoring ~0.1 uA to mA current from a MCU and sensor

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, current-measurement, low-power

Hello I am in need of a current monitor/sensor like INA219 for monitoring current in the range of 0.1 uA to ~ mA. Kindly suggest a way to monitor current in such lower range.
I have a microcontroller and a Accelerometer. I need to monitor the current consumption over a time using a current monitor and Arduino.

Comment: As pointed out by @Drew that the high range causes complexity. What could be the solution if the range is reduced to 0.1uA-500uA. or anything closer to it.

Answer (score 2):

Current consumption over a time period suggests **voltage-to-frequency** or **current-to-frequency conversion**. Current spikes will be integrated into frequency over short time periods, while any microcontroller can collect frequency in its counter/timer. Count overflows can be extended to whatever lengths are needed in software.

The Texas Instruments application note AN240 suggests some circuits:

> AN-240 Wide-Range Current-to-Frequency Converters (Rev. B)

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa594b/snoa594b.pdf

Answer (score 0):

For such low range of current measurements the best approches used are

1.Shunt Ammeter and 2.Feedback Ammeter.

Feedback ammeter are much more accurate than shunt ammeters.

In shunt ammeter the voltage burden (the drop caused by the shunt resistor) will not be considered.

where as in Feedback ammeter the voltage burden will also be taken in to consideration.

The accuracy and least count of the measurement is not only depends on the method -  it depends on Amplifier design, cables used for measurement, ADC resolution and resistance tolerance.

Comment: You call a 10,000:1 dynamic range a "low range"?

Comment: Yes.. in nA and uA range

Comment: You guys are talking about different types of range. The current range is very low, but the dynamic range is very high. That's a good observation photon, it's going to add a lot of complexity to the solution.

Comment: @drew you are right. thanks for your valuable input.. here my point is the modules what he is using in sleep mode they draw very low current. the system should be able to measure all those currents as per his question. and here i am most interested to give him information and make him work that way.

Comment: he is talking about in uA and mA range

Comment: @all, as per the point made by drew that dynamic range is very high which increases the complexity. So is there a simple solution for lets say 0.1 uA to ~500uA?

Answer (score -2):

You can get one of [uCurrent](https://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrent/) clones. They are pretty good and one of the cheapest way to measure very low current with a simple multimeter.